# How to invisibly execute a privilege command in VBScript with a normal user

Tags: vbscript, psexec

Today I do e.g.:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Call WshShell.Run("psexec -u administrator -p pw1234 cmd /c netsh interface ip show address > C:\Output.txt", 2, True)
```

This works, but the command prompt window is always visible for a short time.
I've been searching the web and I've tried everything I could possibly think of to hide/minimize this window, but unfortunately without success.
So I'm afraid that there's no way to run `psexec` in a hidden/minimized window.

But is there perhaps another way to execute a privilege command in VBScript with a normal user where no command prompt window is visible?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I think you're pretty close.  Change your `, 2, True)` to `, 0, True)`, because `2` runs psexec in a minimized window; whereas, `0` should run it in a hidden window.  Also, maybe run your script with `wscript.exe`, not `cscript.exe`.  In fact, both start's `/B` command-line argument and wscript.exe's `//B` command-line argument might help to suppress output.  For example, combining both: `start "" /b wscript.exe //b D:\Scripts\VBScript\RunHidden\runhidden.vbs`  Hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I've never tried ```start "" /b wscript.exe //b myscript.vbs``` before, but unfortunately also with this approach the command prompt window is visible.
May you please test your suggestion again on your computer using the following VBScript command?
```Call WshShell.Run("psexec -u administrator -p pw1234 cmd /c ping 8.8.8.8 -n 4 > D:\X\Output.txt", 0, True)```
This command doesn't require ```psexec``` because it can be executed with any user, but the actual command takes a little more time, so the (unwanted) command prompt window is visible longer. Many thanks.

Comment: Ah, I should have reviewed your command more closely.  Apologies.  I suspect psexec.exe is running hidden, but once it launches cmd.exe and its subsequent child process (netsh.exe or ping.exe) appear as the non-hidden window.

Comment: Maybe give this a try: 1) From an administrator command prompt, run `runas /savecred /user:administrator cmd /c netsh.exe interface ip show address`.  You should be prompted for your administrator credential.  2) Once saved in Windows Credential Manager, any future run of `runas /savecred /user:administrator cmd /c netsh interface ip show address` should reuse your stored Windows credential, without requiring psexec.exe and exposing the credential in plain text.  Once done, you can try changing your script Run command to call `runas` and bypass psexec altogether.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for your review and your new solution suggestion. I really appreciate it.
Actually, I also thought about ```runas```, but there's the problem that you can't add the password to the command.
Yes, ```/savecred``` would be a solution. But first, this parameter is not available in all versions of Windows and second, if you store the administrator password, the user can execute any command using ```runas'`' with administrative privileges.
Only I should be able to run the script after entering the admin password.

Comment: One solution with ```runas``` is:
```Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Call WshShell.Run("runas /u:administrator ""cmd /c netsh interface ip show address > C:\Output.txt""", 2, False)
WScript.Sleep 100
WshShell.SendKeys"p"
WScript.Sleep 10
WshShell.SendKeys"w"
WScript.Sleep 10
WshShell.SendKeys"1"
WScript.Sleep 10
...
WScript.Sleep 10
WshShell.SendKeys"4"
WScript.Sleep 10
WshShell.SendKeys"{ENTER}"```
But also with this (not really nice) approach the command prompt window is visible for a short time.
PS: ```SendKeys``` doesn't work with ```, 0, False)```.

Comment: The solution can be found here:
https://superuser.com/questions/1557565/how-to-run-psexec-minimized-from-a-vb-script-vbs